# になるほど in this sentence

Tags: grammar

I can not understand very well the meaning of "になるほど" in this sentence, from a Japanese Dragon Ball Guide Book.

[image]

> (合体によるパワーアップは、)２人の戦闘力の合計ではなく、掛け算**になるほど**の凄まじさ！

Is it maybe something similar to the construction "The more... the more..."? Or does it have relations with "I see" なるほど?

And, in your opinion, can this translation be correct?

"The Power-Up of the fusion (context: by means of [Potara](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%9E%8D%E5%90%88_(%E3%83%89%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB)) earring), it's something impressive closer/more similar to multiplication rather than a sum of the power forces of the two warriors."

Comment: `凄まじい！` じゃなくて「凄まじ**さ** ！」って書いてありますよね・・

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29513/9831

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, haha! XD
About that link, mmh... What is your idea?

Comment: ^ 「～ほどの」(=「～くらいの」) を調べてみたらいいかもしれません。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`XほどY` (or `XくらいY`) in this context means "Y to the point where X" or "so Y that X". The "the more ～, the more ～" construction is not relevant. [This なるほど](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%88%90%E7%A8%8B) is not relevant, either. You have to add の if the following modified word is a noun. 凄まじい is an adjective, and 凄まじさ is its nominalized form ("-ness").

- 目で見えないほど小さい so small that it's invisible; too small to see
- 驚くほどの値段 the price so expensive/inexpensive that it's surprising; surprising price
- 問題になるほどの大きさ the size big enough to be problematic

So かけ算になるほどの凄まじさ is "intensiveness to the point where it becomes a multiplication" or "the tremendous power going up in a multiplicative manner (rather than the usual additive manner)". The sentence says the fused power increases in a way the fusion of 100 and 100 becomes 10000 rather than 200, for example.