# Question about ほど in this sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning, nuances, particles

I wasn't able to find any explanation of 「ほど」 in these constructions...

> 「そんなテメーに盾突かれる**ほど**頭に来る事はない」

In any case I would like to ask whether I am getting the general meaning right. Besides that I would like to ask if there is a certain nuance implied  by the 「**ほど**」 here

With nuances I mean if it rather means:

a) Even if your struggling to that extent

or

b) With that amount of struggling (rather "neutral")

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61345/9831

Comment: This particular case seems at odds with the explanation provided in the answer on the linked question.

Comment: I kind of felt like that myself when I read the explanation given in the linked question; however I believe that the general principle is applicable here as well. If you are a native speaker of Japanese you are most probably right (and I just interpreted the explanation in a way to make it fit for me). In any case I understood this 「盾突かれるほど」construction as "that action not being intense enough" to lead to 「頭に来る事」. If you have any other thoughts I'd love you to share theme here.

Comment: Well, I see that you translated "テメーに盾突かれる" to "having you struggle", but it's more like "to have you oppose/disobey me" or "to be opposed/disobeyed by you".　盾突く= disobey, oppse, etc. https://jisho.org/search/%E7%9B%BE%E7%AA%81%E3%81%8F

Comment: You are correct I will fix that. In any case I thought your original comment was referring to how the linked explanation does not fit the meaning of the construction here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer in the linked question basically applies here as well except that what comes before ほど does not have to be a noun for the sentence to mean "No C is as B as A." It can also be the attributive form (連体形) of a verb. But you can make your sentence structurally the same as the ones in that answer by nominalizing the verb with こと:

> そんなテメーに盾突かれるほど頭に来ることはない。
>   そんなテメーに盾突かれる**こと**ほど頭に来ることはない。

And they mean the same thing:

> Nothing is as infuriating as being opposed by you.
>   There is nothing as infuriating as being opposed by you.

In other words, the speaker is saying that being opposed by the listener is the most infuriating thing in the world.

In English, it might be more common to use a comparison of inequality in this situation:

> Nothing is more infuriating than being opposed by you.
>   There is nothing more infuriating than being opposed by you.

(P.S. Unless space is an issue, こと is usually written in kana when it is used as a formal noun.)