# Understanding「それでも時に凍えそうになるほど人の世は厳しい」

Tags: grammar

> 人は一人でなど強くなれん
>
> 皆で支え合い、温め合い
>
> **それでも時に凍えそうになるほど人の世は厳しい**

I have difficulty figuring out the overall meaning of this sentence. What 時に means? sometimes? Does 凍えそうになるほど人の世は厳しい mean "friends can be strict to the extent that makes you to tremble"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What 時に means? sometimes?

Right! 時に means "sometimes". 時に sounds more literary than [時々]{ときどき}.

> Does 凍えそうになるほど人の世は厳しい mean "friends can be strict to the extent that makes you to tremble"?

[人]{ひと}の[世]{よ}, literary "world of human", is almost synonymous to [世間]{せけん} or [世]{よ}の[中]{なか}, "the world", "society".

I think your understanding of ～になるほど is correct. 「それでも時に凍えそうになるほど人の世は厳しい」 literally means "Still, the world/society is sometimes harsh/severe to the extent that it almost freezes you". Please rewrite it to what sounds more natural in your language.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, here「時に」means sometimes, like 時々、たまに. Per Google's definition:

> 《副詞的に》 時々。また、たまに。何かのはずみに。どうかすると。

凍えそう: the verb stem of 凍える{こごえる} (to freeze) + clitic suffix そう
looks like (it's) about to freeze

になるほど is explained in detail [here in this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/56248/30454). It expresses a degree to which something else is described as (by a modifier).

> でも時に凍えそうになるほど人の世は厳しい

can be roughly rendered as:

> But sometimes the world can be so cruel that it feels like freezing.

Or

> But sometimes the world can be freezingly cruel.